# Eclipse CDT - how to transfer "Paths and Symbols" between checkouts

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In my checkout, there are many "C++ Eclipse projects".
To get Eclipse to index symbols, classes, etc. I manually add the paths to headers to each of these Eclipse C++ project folders in the **Paths and Symbols** menu.

Unfortunately, I cannot check in the `.cproject` files that contain this information so whenever I need to checkout a new copy . . . I have to redo everything.

**QUESTION**

How can I transfer these modifications to my "Path and Symbols" property of the Eclipse C++ project in the new checkout?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this, but it seems like `File | Export | C/C++ | C/C++ Project Settings` (and then `Import` the same into the new project) should work.

That said, it's worth noting that CDT has a feature that allows you to avoid manually specifying the include paths in `Paths and Symbols` to begin with: the build output parser.

The idea is that if your project uses a build system whose build output contains (or can be configured to contain) the full compiler invocation commands (things like `g++ -I include/path/1 -I include/path/2 -o MyClass.o MyClass.cpp`), CDT is able to parse this output and pick up the include paths automatically.

The build output parser can be configured in `Project Properties | C/C++ General | Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. | Providers | CDT GCC Build Output Parser` (or replace `GCC` with whatever toolchain you're using).

This way, information about necessary include paths is contained in *one* place (your build script, e.g. `makefile` or similar, which presumably can be and is checked into the repository), and in each checkout of the project CDT's build output parser can pick up these settings automatically.